# jquery checkall checkbox plus reset

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using the following jquery to achieve check all effect in a php page:-

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#checkall").click(function(){
        if($("#checkall").attr('checked')){
            $(".department").attr('checked', true);
        }else{
            $(".department").attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkall" name="check_all" />

<input type="checkbox" name="department[]" class="department" value=""  checked = "checked"/>
```

and the check all and uncheck all effect works fine. However, it doesn't work with the reset button in the form. How shall I modify the jquery? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#checkall").click(function(){
    $(".department").prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked') ); 
});
```

[The jQuery `.prop()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) has a section describing why this should be used instead of manipulating the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/JCWaT/

My old reply in here: [checkbox check all option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380555/checkbox-check-all-option)

Hope fits the need `:)`

**or for your need** http://jsfiddle.net/kJCcP/

**code**

```
$('input[name="Company"],input[name="Country"]').click(function(){

          $(this).nextAll('input[name="'+this.name+'Sub"]').prop('checked',this.checked);

});
​
```

**OR**

```
$('#checkall').click(function() {

    $(this).nextAll('.department').prop('checked', this.checked);

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.prop` instead `.attr`, see ***[the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52xLA/)***.

```
$(function(){
    $("#checkall").click(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            $(".department").prop('checked', true);
        }else{
            $(".department").prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});​
```

And your code could be even short:

```
$(function(){
    $("#checkall").click(function(){
        $(".department").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
});​
```