# check all the checkbox using checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [checkbox check all option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380555/checkbox-check-all-option)

```
<form action='ppc_logistic-control_number.php' target='_blank' method='post'>
<b>Sample Program</b><br>
<input type='checkbox'>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
print"<input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value='$i->logi_id' value='$i->ppc_id' style='margin-left:-5px'><br>";
}                       
?>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="gen"/>
```

what jquery or javascript code i need to place here in order: when i check the checkbox in top of 5 checkbox, all the checkbox will have a check, and when I remove the checkbox that ive previously check also the 5 checkbox will remove thier check.

---

sample:
[image]

---

sample demo thank you so much.

Comment: there is no link to a demo. And, you can't have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: thx Mr. Alessandro Minoccheri

Comment: Try this link 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259335/select-all-checkbox][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259335/select-all-checkbox

Comment: ahh ok just hoping ;-( thx Sir/Madam  11684

Answer (score 4):

**[Check DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3EjUF/)**

This will be the basic logic.

**ID** in the HTML page should be unique.. Try using **class** instead

Answer (score 1):

using javascript

```
<input type="checkbox" value="select" onclick="javascript:checkAll()" name="allbox" class="table_ckbox" /></th>
```

function checkAll()

```
{

for (var i=0;i<document.delete_form.elements.length;i++)
{
    var e=document.delete_form.elements[i];
    if ((e.name != 'allbox') && (e.type=='checkbox'))
    {
        e.checked=document.delete_form.allbox.checked;
    }
}
return false;
 }
```

in php where you use allcheck box

```
foreach($listArr as $list) {

 echo '<td><input type="checkbox" value="'.$list['id'].'" name="module[]" /></td>';
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

***Try this***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Sample Program</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7rc2.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form action='ppc_logistic-control_number.php' target='_blank' method='post'>
<b>Sample Program</b><br>
<div id="check-b">
<input type='checkbox' id="top-checkbox">
<?php
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
print"<input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value='$i->logi_id' value='$i->ppc_id' style='margin-left:-5px'><br>";
}                       
?>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="gen"/>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#top-checkbox').change(function(){
        var isChecked = $(this).attr("checked");
        if (isChecked) {
        $('#check-b').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);   
        }else{
            $('#check-b').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);   
        }
    });

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 is it working? if not please inform me.. Thanks

Comment: It works fine when i use your code. but when i try to put that code in my actual code it does not work? maybe because my checkbox is inside a <td></td>? or because i use many jquery... heading like jquery1.8....

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample showing check and uncheck checkbox based on class.

You might want to make class of first element to `parent` and all others to `child`, the below code will simply ease your job

NOTE: Copy and paste this code in a html file, and play around, then you will get a good understanding.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".parent").click(function(){
        var check = $(this).attr('checked');
        if(check=="checked")
        {
         $(".child").attr('checked','checked');
        }
        else
         $(".child").removeAttr('checked');
   });
 });
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" id="vehicle1" class="parent" value="Bike">Parent<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" id="vehicle2" class="child" value="Car">Child 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" id="vehicle3" class="child" value="Car">Child 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle4" id="vehicle4" class="child" value="Car">Child 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle5" id="vehicle5" class="child" value="Car">Child 1<br />

</body>
</html>
```